# Unable to train/fine-tune with PReLU in caffe

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, face-recognition

I am working in face recognition with deep neural network. I am using the [CASIA-webface](http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/english/CASIA-WebFace-Database.html) database of 10575 classes for training a deep CNN (used by CASIA, see the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7923) for details) of 10 Convolution, 5 Pooling and 1 Fully Connected layer. For the activation it uses `"ReLU"` function. I was able to successfully train it using **[caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe)** and obtained the desired performance.

My problem is that, *I am unable to train/fine-tune the same CNN using `"PReLU"` activation*. At first, I thought that a simple replace of `"ReLU"` with `"PReLU"` will do the job. However, none of *fine-tuning* (from caffemodel  which was learned with `"ReLU"`) and *learn from scratch* strategies worked.

In order to simplify the learning problem, I reduced the training dataset significantly only with 50 classes. However, yet the CNN was unable to learn with `"PReLU"`, whereas it was able to learn with `"ReLU"`.

In order to understand that my caffe works fine with `"PReLU"`, I verified  it by running simple networks (with both `"ReLU"` and `"PReLU"`) using cifar10 data and it worked.

I would like to know from the community if anyone has similar observations. Or if anyone can provide any suggestion to overcome this problem.

Comment: Have you changed any of your training parameters?  Learning rate or convergence epsilon, for example?  Fine tuning the model sometimes takes fine-tuning a parameter or two.  Also, I'm not certain where the P/ReLU functions are inserted: the paper doesn't call them out, so I assume them in the usual spots (adjacent to POOL).

Comment: Yes I tried with different range of training parameters as you mentioned. P/ReLU is inserted after the Conv layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between `"ReLU"` and `"PReLU"` activation is that the latter activation function has a non-zero slope for negative values of input, and that this slope can be learned from the data. It was observed that these properties make the training more robust to the random initialization of the weights.
I used `"PReLU"` activation for fine-tuning nets that were trained originally with `"ReLU"`s and I experienced faster and more robust convergence.

My suggestion is to replace `"ReLU"` with the following configuration

```
layer {
  name: "prelu"
  type: "PReLU"
  bottom: "my_bottom"
  top: "my_bottom" # you can make it "in-place" to save memory
  param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 0 }
  prelu_param { 
    filler: { type: "constant" val: 0 } 
    channel_shared: false
  }
}
```

Note that by initializing the negative slope to 0, the `"PReLU"` activations are in-fact the same as `"ReLU"` so you start the fine tuning from exactly the same spot as your original net.

Also note that I explicitly set the learning rate and decay rate coefficients (1 and 0 resp.) -- you might need to tweak these params a bit, though I believe setting the `decay_weight` to any value other than zero is not wise.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to train fine using PReLu for my network, albeit with a bit lower accuracy that using ReLu. And yes, I simply swapped out ReLu with PReLu as well.

However, I have almost consistently noticed that PReLU converges much faster than ReLu. So, maybe you need to lower your learning rate?

Comment: I tried with many different range of learning rate from 0.1 to 0.00001. I use the default SGD solver.

Comment: I have the same experience: taking net trained with ReLU, fine-tuning it to a different DB using PReLU works much better.

Answer (score 1):

Two basic observations:

- PReLU is not guaranteed to produce results more accurate than those with ReLU.  It worked better with AlexNet on ImageNet, but this merely suggests further research and refinement; it doesn't necessarily transfer to other applications.
- CIFAR, ImageNet, and CASIA-webface are not identical applications.

You've already done the proper first step, changing the learning rate.  Next, I would try tweaking the command-line arguments: change the convergence epsilon, momentum, weight decay, or other internal tuning parameters.  Sometimes, it takes a tweak there to take advantage of even a minor topology change.

Change the input batch size.  Are you allowed to alter the topology in other ways, such as altering a convolution layer?  You might see what you get with a different approach to the CONV2 filters.

Comment: Several recent work obtained better results on the same CNN and DB by replacing ReLU with PReLU. Therefore, my aim is to achieve better performance by following this and not to alter the network config.

I can go for changing convergence epsilon, momentum, etc. But question is at what learning rate I should change those?

I have some uncertainty about solver type. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: Okay; that deletes several of my suggestions.  For the remaining ones, I would try with the original training rate, changing the others by a 1.5x factor in each direction.  I'm not as familiar with the major step of changing the solver, but ... are you using SoftMax?

Comment: Yes, SoftMax. I am using SGD solver. I do not know if changing the solver type (e.g., ADAM) will help or not!

Comment: Well, the obvious response :-) is to try other solvers to see what they do.